# Rewriting URLs with a query string

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting

I am running into a headache trying to get some url rewriting working on a wordpress website, running Centos 6 for operating system.

This is what I am trying to achieve.

**Current URL = http://www.downer.co.uk/property-details/?propertyidtag=508362_166879S**

I would like this to be re-written to

**http://www.downer.co.uk/property-details/508362_166879S/**

I must of tried every tuturial online with absolutely no success. 
Please help me!!

Comment: what is `property-details`? show us what you have so far.

Comment: property-details is a wordpress template page for displaying the property details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cracked it. :) Here is my solution.

```
add_rewrite_rule('^(property-details)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&propertyidtag=$matches[2]','top');
add_filter('query_vars', 'foo_my_query_vars');
function foo_my_query_vars($vars){
$vars[] = 'propertyidtag';
return $vars;
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: could you please mention all steps involve?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to make sure to register your public query vars with WordPress so it recognizes your rewrite rule vars.

Add this code on your `functions.php` file:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^(tips)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]&filter_id=$matches[3]','top');

add_filter('query_vars', 'foo_my_query_vars');
function foo_my_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = 'id';
    $vars[] = 'filter_id';
    return $vars;
}
```

After that, enter on your **Permalinks Settings** page to flush your permalinks, just save it again and Wordpress system will rewrite the `.htaccess` file.

You can access your variables as follows:

```
$id = get_query_var('id');
$filter_id = get_query_var('filter_id');
```

This `rewrite_rule` works only for level/cat/1 (1 being the `filter_id`).

Comment: add_rewrite_rule('^(property)/?', 'property-details?propertyidtag=$matches[1]','top');

add_filter('query_vars', 'foo_my_query_vars');
function foo_my_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = 'propertyidtag';
    return $vars;
}

Comment: Thats what I have added to my functions.php but I am getting a 500 server error, with too many redirect in the logs

Comment: how do i  register public query vars with WordPress ? sorry i am new on wordpress